# Contentful CMS data layer does not reach my Gatsby/React blog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system, gatsby, contentful

I was using local .md files for the Gatsby data layer, but now i need  Contentful CMS integration.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {
const { createPage } = boundActionCreators

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const blogPost = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js')

resolve(
  graphql(
    `
      {
        allContentfulBlog(limit: 500) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      console.log(result.errors)
      reject(result.errors)
    }
    result.data.allContentfulBlog.edges.forEach(edge => {
      createPage({
        path: edge.node.slug,
        component: blogPost,
        context: {
          slug: edge.node.slug,
        },
      })
    })
    return
   })
  )
 })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, boundActionCreators, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = boundActionCreators
}
```

This is my gatsby-node.js file.

Terminal gives:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulBlog' of undefined.

On Contentful.com, the name of the content type is Blog.

I have attached a screenshot of the terminal
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB5WC.png).

Any hints anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulBlog' of undefined.

is the result of

> can not query field 'slug' on type 'ContentfulBlog'

Can you share your content model maybe? I don't know if you have seen the gatsby-contentful-starter. It ships with a content model – so you could have a look there too. :)

Comment: Hello, how can i share the content model here? and no i didn't know gatsby-contentful-starter existed, thank you, i will check it out.

Comment: For this question here probably some screenshots would have been enough. But in general for sharing content models `content-import` and `content-export` are the tools to use. they are available on npm. :)

Comment: I ended up deleting exports.onCreateNode function that was responsible for creating  slugs from titles(i think) that i got from the gatsby-starter-blog plugin, and everything seems fine.